# Is it possible to refresh a single UITableViewCell in a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableView` using `UITableViewCell`s.
Each `UITableViewCell` has 2 buttons. Clicking these buttons will change an image in a `UIImageView` within the cell.

Is it possible to refresh each cell separately to display the new image?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Once you have the indexPath of your cell, you can do something like:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

In Xcode 4.6 and higher:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

You can set whatever your like as animation effect, of course.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but of course if you were only refreshing a single cell you'd probably want to use `[NSArray arrayWithObject:]` instead.

Comment: Also, in this situation, the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` are unnecessary.

Comment: @kubi hi, can you explain why they are not necessary?

Comment: The OP isn't animating anything, so there's no need to call the begin/endupdates

Comment: @Romain I am confused that why we call these two functions `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. I find that a lot of examples don't call these methods. Can you tell the different?

Comment: As long as the method doesn't say **deprecated** in the last public Xcode version, all iOS versions should be fine.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Actually as I have been told many times by SO user "rmaddy", just because an iOS API is deprecated, doesn't mean you can't use it.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff true, but at some point it could be replaced or will change its behavior. It's better to handle deprecations asap

Comment: @AlejandroIván Agreed. I believe it does state that on Apple's website. I guess the only reason to use a deprecated API, is to retain support for an older version of iOS.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff I believe that's the reason. That's why I mentioned that as long as the API isn't deprecated, the code should be fine. The problem will arise when that deprecated API disappears/changes behavior and thus the app will not work properly.

Comment: @kubi mentioned that in this situation, beginUpdates() and endUpdates() are unnecessary, may I know why is this the case? Also, then what situation are they necessary?

Comment: @happiehappie `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` consolidate a bunch of changes into a single animation. If you're only doing one reload, there's no need to consolidate anything.

Answer (score 34):

I tried just calling `-[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`, but that didn't work. But, the following works for me for example. I `alloc` and `release` the `NSArray` for tight memory management.

```
- (void)reloadRow0Section0 {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [indexPaths release];
}
```

Comment: Is [indexPaths release] necessary here? I thought you only needed that if you alloc'd the object yourself.

Comment: He did alloc the indexPaths array. But the better question is why he thinks "tight memory management" is necessary. Autorelease will do the job perfectly well here.

Answer (score 22):

Swift:

```
func updateCell(path:Int){
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: path, inSection: 1)

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) //try other animations
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Where to call this method?

Answer (score 17):

`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` is fine, but still will force `UITableViewDelegate` methods to fire.

The simplest approach I can imagine is:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

It's **important** to invoke your `configureCell:` implementation on main thread, as **it wont work on non-UI thread** (the same story with `reloadData`/`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`). Sometimes it might be helpful to add:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
});
```

It's also worth to avoid work that would be done outside of the currently visible view:

```
BOOL cellIsVisible = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound;
if (cellIsVisible)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want delegate to be called?

Comment: This is the best approach since it does not force the tableview to scroll all the way to the top as opposed to reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: or reloadData methods.

Comment: I did this and ended up being caught by the fact that the cell was recycled

Answer (score 16):

If you are using custom TableViewCells, the generic

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

does not effectively answer this question **unless you leave the current view** and come back. Neither does the first answer.

To successfully reload your first table view cell **without switching views**, use the following code:

```
//For iOS 5 and later
- (void)reloadTopCell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Insert the following **refresh method** which calls to the above method so you can custom reload only the top cell (or the entire table view if you wish):

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
    //call to the method which will perform the function
    [self reloadTopCell];

    //finish refreshing 
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Now that you have that sorted, inside of your `viewDidLoad` add the following:

```
//refresh table view
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

You now have a custom refresh table feature that will reload the top cell. To reload the entire table, add the

`[self.tableView reloadData];` to your new refresh method.

If you wish to reload the data every time you switch views, implement the method:

```
//ensure that it reloads the table view data when switching to this view
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 :

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a UITableView extension with Swift 5:

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView
{    
    func updateRow(row: Int, section: Int = 0)
    {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        
        self.beginUpdates()
        self.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.endUpdates()
    }
    
}
```

Call with

```
self.tableView.updateRow(row: 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to update these answers slightly with the new literal syntax in iOS 6--you can use Paths = @[indexPath] for a single object, or Paths = @[indexPath1, indexPath2,...] for multiple objects.

Personally, I've found the literal syntax for arrays and dictionaries to be immensely useful and big time savers.  It's just easier to read, for one thing.  And it removes the need for a nil at the end of any multi-object list, which has always been a personal bugaboo.  We all have our windmills to tilt with, yes? ;-)

Just thought I'd throw this into the mix.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Say Greg,  What's actually an example of that syntax there, please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I need the upgrade cell but I want close the keyboard.
If I use

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: path, inSection: 1)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) //try other animations
tableView.endUpdates()
```

the keyboard disappear