# reload the data of specific uitableview cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to refresh a single UITableViewCell in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview)

Sorry if the question is stupid but instead of using `[mytableview reloaddata]`,how can we reload the data of only specific `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Below answers are correct. Please be kind enough to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want UITableView's [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) method.  I've linked the documentation for you.

All you need to provide is the index paths to the cell(s) you want to redraw.