# How to update a cell in a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm using Delegate methods to get data from child view and want to dynamically edit my table in the root view.

So I would like to do something like this in my viewWillAppear method :

```
[myTable setCell:newCell atIndex:i];
```

What should I do ? Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to refresh a single UITableViewCell in a UITableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I made it using :

```
[cellules beginUpdates];
[cellules reloadData];
[cellules endUpdates];
```

I used reloadData because it's a little TableView (3 cells), for big TableViews this should be better :

```
– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

Thanks anyway !

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If the cell is visible, you can also call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` on the table view and then modify the properties or contents of that cell -- you might notice that some of the Xcode project templates use this approach.

Comment: Yep, I used reloadData because I've a small Table View (only 3 cells), but of course I should use cellForRowAtIndexPath. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

put your code in between:

```
[myTable beginUpdates];
//your code
[myTable setCell:newCell atIndex:i];
//your code end
[myTable endUpdates];
```

Comment: No I was meaning, is there a way to update my cell looking like this function ?