# how can i acess a cells object if selected

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, tablecell

i seem to be having some difficulty trying to access a particular cell, i just need to change one of its objects when i select it in the tableview.  There must be a way more efficient way than just calling reloadData all over again.  Because thats the only way i could make a table cell look different, by rebuilding it when i select on one.  Thanks for all the help :)

```
[self updatePreferences];
[tableView reloadData];
```

This is all i have atm on the method where it handles the interaction with table cells.

Comment: You can call tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.To reload a single cell.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]]; 
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the cell a custom one and add a method to it like update or refresh.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  CustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [cell refresh];
}
```