# Static tableView updates only when selecting a row

Tags: uitableview, static, reloaddata

I have a UITableViewController that contains a static UITableView from which you can request quotes and buy or sell a stock. I handle all communications to the backend in a separate ServerCommunicator class. When a request completes, the ServerCommunicator calls the delegate (the tableViewController) which updates the fields in the tableView.

In the main queue, I call tableView.reloadData and display the fields.

The problem is that the fields display immediately but show stale values. When I select a row by clicking on it, however, value is updated.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class AddStockTableViewController: UITableViewController, ServerCommunicatorDelegate {

………..

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameLabel.hidden = true
    symbolLabel.hidden = true
    quoteLabel.hidden = true
    changeLabel.hidden = true
     ….….   

}

@IBAction func getQuoteAction(sender: UIButton) {

    if let symbol = getQuoteTextField.text {
        serverCommunicator.updateQuote(symbol, delegate: self)
    }
}

func didCompleteRequest(data : NSData)
{
    quote = parseQuote(data)

    self.symbolLabel.text = "(\(self.quote.symbol))"
    self.nameLabel.text = self.quote.name
    self.quoteLabel.text = "\(self.quote.currentPrice)"
    self.changeLabel.text = “\(self.quote.change)"

    ……. 


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.nameLabel.hidden = false
        self.symbolLabel.hidden = false
        self.quoteLabel.hidden = false
        ………
     }

   }


class ServerCommunicator
{
    func sendRequest(requestURL : String, requestString : String, delegate : ServerCommunicatorDelegate)
    {
       if let requestData = requestString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false){
          let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: requestURL)!)
          request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

          let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
          let task = urlSession.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: requestData, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                delegate.didCompleteRequest(data)
            }
        })
        task.resume()

    } else {
        print("Could not encode requestString to data")
    }
  }
 …….
}
```

Comment: Which thread is ServerCommunicator running on?

Comment: ServerCommunicator runs on the main thread but the completion handler for uploadTaskWithRequest runs on another thread. The completion handler calls didCompleteRequest when then queues tableView.reloadData on the main thread.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Comment: It appears that your data is not available (i.e.) updated when you invoke `reloadData`. There seem to be a few class variables  in your view controller. Do those need to be there, rather than at the `UITableViewCell` level? Also, have you verified that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` triggered by the `reloadData` returns proper values (not cached, old, stale values). It seems to be a reasonable assumption.

Comment: How did you eventually solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** such thing as *Static TableView Update*. All updates are supposed to occur through a cell change, and such a change shall be triggered by some kind of table view or table view cell refresh.

An update not showing up in a `UITableViewCell` indicate that the cell is cached and not reloading fresh data.

`reloadData` in the `UITableView` triggers reloading all table view cells. Make certain that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns fresh data, and that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` uses proper id.

Finally, reloading all cells if you change a single one is not best practice. [Is it possible to refresh a single UITableViewCell in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview) Yes it is.

Comment: Sorry, may be poor choice of words on my part. I meant that I am using static cells instead of dynamic prototypes. Therefore, I don't implement methods such as cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Oh, then the answer is easy. Going from static cells to dynamic cells is a snap. Click that checkbox in IB, and implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, returning dynamic cells you actually control. Then apply my response. You can be done in 10 mins flat!