# Updating TableView text label with JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, ios8

Is it possible to update only the Text label in a Tableview without using reloaddata to reset it all?

Comment: No. Its not possible without reloading

Comment: Do you want to update only one specific cell's text label or all cells, or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. Just the cell.textlabel.text I need to update it every 30 seconds.

Comment: You can store references to the labels of the visible cells in a separate array and update their text property according your needs.

Comment: @hacker2007 - That will work until the user scrolls a cell offscreen.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview

Comment: Isn't that enough? If one row moves offscreen another row moves on screen. For the new row tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: provides a new cell with the updated text provided by your datasource. You can add this label to your array and remove the one you don't need anymore in tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks