# Multiple UITableViewCells each with UIProgressView very slow to update

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, uitableview, uiprogressview

I am making a game which has 10 `UITableViewCells` in a `UITableView`. Each of the 10 `UITableViewCells` has one `UIProgressView` plus a lot of other views. I update the `UITableView` every 1/10th of a second, this is very slow and lags on older devices. I update it every 1/10th second for UX, gives a smooth progress view feel to game.

Is there a way to just update just the Progress Views in each cell individually rather than having to call the `tableView.reloadData()` that will update all the views in each cell?

**Code example:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "businessCell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessCell

            cell.progress.progress = Float( businessArray[indexPath.row-1].getCurrentProgress() )

        //lots of other views are updated here

        return cell
    }
}
```

**could I maybe change this line:**

```
cell.progress.progress = Float( businessArray[indexPath.row-1].getCurrentProgress() )
```

**to something like this:**

```
cell.progress.progress = someVarLocalToViewControllerContainingTableView[indexPath.row]
```

**and when I update this local var it would update only the progressView or something?
I have tried many ways but cannot figure out how to do this...**

Comment: of course it's possible to update just progress bar frame in each tableview - that should be the proper solution. Reloading whole tableview just for that it's a disaster.

But you should also show us the code you are using to update progression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update a progress for a specific cell, then call this

```
func reloadProgress(at index: Int) {
     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BusinessCell {
            cell.progress.progress = Float( businessArray[index - 1].getCurrentProgress() )
        }
}
```

If you need to reload all bars in the table:

```
func reloadProgress() {
        for indexPath in tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [] {

            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BusinessCell {
                cell.progress.progress = Float( businessArray[indexPath.row - 1].getCurrentProgress() )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly, never thought of doing it this way thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
self.tableView .reloadRows(at: <[IndexPath]>, with: <UITableViewRowAnimation>)
```

rather than using `tableView.reloadData()`

Please check below link:

- [Is it possible to refresh a single UITableViewCell in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview)

It might help in your scenario.

Comment: I know this, however there is about 12 other views that get updated in each cell every time the cell is reloaded. I am trying to just update the progressViews in the cell and not waste cpu updating every other view in the cell.